# $\text{Col}(A)=\text{Row}(A) \implies A=A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> I know that if we have $A=A^T$, the column space equals row space. Does the converse hold true? Does $\text{Col}(A)=\text{Row}(A) \implies A=A^T$?

---

I cannot think of a counter example. But I'm not equipped with enough linear algebra to formally prove it. Any simple counter example or a direction towards a proof would help.

**Edit:** To be clear, I am not talking about the rank of column space and row space being equal. It's the row space and the column space being equal.

Comment: Have you tried any simple upper triangular $2 \times 2$ examples?

Comment: Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. The row space is $[1\;\;1]^T,\;\; [0\;\;1]^T$, while the column space is $[1\;\;0]^T,\;\; [1\;\;1]^T$. They are not equal. I want to find a matrix whose column space and row space are equal, but it is not equal to its transpose.

Comment: The row (or column) space is not a pair of points, it is **all** the points that can be reached. With the preceding example, the column and row spaces are both $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Well, if their bases aren't equal, they won't be equal, right?

Comment: The column space is $\{ Ax \}_x$ and the row space is $\{ A^T y \}_y$. They have nothing to do with bases as such.

Comment: Alright, I understood it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Any non-symmetric invertible matrix is a counterexample.